# Perl - Use of uninitialized value within %frequency in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: perl, hash, initialization

Not entirely sure why but for some reason i cant print the hash value outside the while loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

opendir(D, "cwd" );
my @files = readdir(D);
closedir(D); 

foreach $file (@files)
{
        open F, $file or die "$0: Can't open $file : $!\n";
        while ($line = <F>) {
                chomp($line);
                $line=~ s/[-':!?,;".()]//g;
                $line=~ s/^[a-z]/\U/g;
                        @words = split(/\s/, $line);
                        foreach  $word (@words) {
                                 $frequency{$word}++;
                                $counter++;
                }

        } 
         close(F);

        print "$file\n";
        print "$ARGV[0]\n";
        print "$frequency{$ARGV[0]}\n";
        print "$counter\n";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
cheers.

Comment: How do you invoke your script? `perl the-script.pl someWord`? The `$ARGV[0]` asks for the first command line argument. Aside from that, you might want to rewrite that script to `use strict` etc. It should also die pretty soon, when it wants to open the parent directory `..` as a file. You'll want to check that the file is a normal file, e.g. `next unless -f $file`.

Comment: ALWAYS: `use strict; use warnings;`. Declare `%frequency` outside the loop.

Comment: @M42 `%frequency` is not declared as lexical, and he is not using strict, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
print "$frequency{$ARGV[0]}\n";
```

Expects you to have an argument to your script, e.g. `perl script.pl argument`. If you have no argument, `$ARGV[0]` is undefined, but it will stringify to the empty string. This empty string is a valid key in the hash, but the value is undefined, hence your warning

```
Use of uninitialized value within %frequency in concatenation (.) or string
```

But you should also see the warning

```
Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[0] in hash element
```

And it is a very big mistake not to include that error in this question.

Also, when using `readdir`, you get *all* the files in the directory, including directories. You might consider filtering the files somewhat.

Using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Is something that will benefit you very much, so add that to your script.

Answer (score 0):

I had originally written this,

> There is no `%frequency` defined at the top level of your program.
>
> When `perl` sees you reference `%frequency` inside the inner-most
>   loop, it will auto-vivify it, in that scratchpad (lexical scope).
>
> This means that when you exit the inner-most loop (`foreach  $word
>   (@words)`), the auto-vivified `%frequency` is out of scope and
>   garbage-collected. Each time you enter that loop, a *new, different*
>   variable will be auto-vivified, and then discarded.
>
> When you later refer to `%frequency` in your `print`, yet another new,
>   different `%frequency` will be created.

… but then realized that you had forgotten to `use strict`, and Perl was being generous and giving you a *global* `%frequency`, which ironically is probably what you meant. So, this answer is *wrong* in your case … but declaring the scope of `%frequency` would probably be good form, regardless.

These other, “unrelated” notes are still useful perhaps, or else I'd delete the answer altogether:

---

As @TLP mentioned, you should probably also skip directories (at least) in your file loop. A quick way to do this would be `my @files = grep { -f "cwd/$_" } (readdir D)`; this will filter the list to contain only files.

I'm further suspicious that you named a directory `"cwd"` … are you perhaps meaning the current working directory? In all the major OS'es in use today, that directory is referenced as “`.`” — you're looking for a directory literally named `"cwd"`?